# HTML Doesn't Appear Correctly When Loading Information From Server Using Angular4

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular

I just started learning Angular and I'm trying to create a character gallery for this roleplaying community I'm part of. You can see it here: http://bnf-front-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/rollcall (you might have to click Home then go back to Roll Call; that's also a problem). My problem is that sometimes the [character boxes appear out of line and on top of one another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cndjx.png). I'm sure if this is an Angular problem (the way I'm loading the information from my Mongo database) or a HTML/CSS problem. Either way I don't know what to do. Is there something I'm doing wrong or something that I should add?

Is it the way I'm [loading the information from my server](https://github.com/PavanJakhu/BnF-Front-Site/blob/master/src/app/roll-call/character.service.ts#L16)? Because I know there somewhat different ways of doing it with or without Promises. This is how I'm doing my for loop in HTML, maybe I'm doing something wrong there? I think I could add `| async` after the statement but I would have to use Observables to do that if I remember correctly.

```
<li *ngFor="let character of characters">
    <a href={{character.profileLink}}>
        <img src={{character.avatarLink}}/>
        <span>{{character.name}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is [my source code for that page](https://github.com/PavanJakhu/BnF-Front-Site/tree/master/src/app/roll-call). I'm using Angular 4 by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Angular sanitizes by default. Check out DOMSanitizer in the angular documentation.

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer